# Can I go back to get unique loot?

Tags: thief

I just finished the first mission (Lockdown), and was disappointed to see that I'd only found 2/4 unique loot items.

Will I get the opportunity to go back later to find it, or do I have to restart/reload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replay all client and main missions (chapters) by finding their original starting point in The City. You can then try to find all the loot you missed or complete the optional thieving challenges. You can not go back to certain parts of a mission alone, you'll have to complete the entire mission again to collect the loot.

However, the starting points are not marked on the map, so you'll have to find them first.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhkjknnBYRI) is a video with all the starting points of the main missions. To replay chapter one you will first have to complete the second chapter, because the starting point will not be accessible until then.